# Camel Netty 4 component consumer : Handling messages from multiple producers

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, gps, apache-camel

I have a scenario in which multiple GPS devices are sending data to a TCP connection. I am using Camel Netty 4 to create a consumer which listens on a port. Now GPS devices first send login message which contains the device number. After that these devices start sending the loation messages which do not contain any information about the device. 
So my issue is to how to identify location messages for different devices. Is any tcp session kind of thing is maintaind by Netty 4 consumer for each GPS device connection. Below is my route definition

### from("netty4:tcp://0.0.0.0:5150?sync=true&decoder=#messageDecoder&encoder=#messageEncoder").to("activemq:queue:messageQueue")

Comment: Can anyone help me please on this issue.

Comment: @JimGarrison- Please advice.